# Create an executable jar

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, compilation

My project in eclipse is more or less like this:

```
prj
    src
        pack1
            file11.java(main)
            file12.java
        pack2
            file21.java
JRE
Referenced Libraries
    lib1.jar
    lib2.jar
filesave.txt
filename.txt
```

I tried to create a executable jar using the eclipse function, but when is lunch it can't found the main class.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your manifest file whether the Main-Class is set or not. If it is set and still program doesn't work , try :
1. Create a bat file such as run.bat in the same folder where jar file is located.
2. Edit the run.bat file. Type "java -jar jar-fle-name" in the bat file.
3. Double click the bat file.

Comment: Thanks i found the error, it was a class not defined in a jar, which I could notice due to the bat file.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is the manifest file is missing or incomplete. There should be an option to set the manifest file when you create the jar in eclipse. The file should include the name of the your main class, e.g.:

```
Main-Class: pack1.file11
```

For more info on manifest files, read [the official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html). The "Setting an Application's entry point" section discusses the main class.

Comment: Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path:...
Main-Class: main.Prj

(from file MANIFEST.MF in the folder META-INF

Answer (score 0):

In your java project 1st run the Java file which contains `Main-method` using Eclipse `Run as -> java application`. Once you have done you will get the main class when you will going to create executable jar.